# Comparator function in C++ meaning and working?

Tags: c++

```
bool comp(const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int,int>& b){
    if (v[a.first]>v[b.first]) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(v[a.first] == v[b.first] && a.second < b.second){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So, I was going through a code and I came across this comparator function for sorting a vector of pairs. Now, I am fairly new to C++. I tried reading on other questions as to how does this comparator work? But I am not able to understand. Why is the return type bool? And what does returning the value true means?

Comment: I am really sorry but `v` is just an array containing integer values. Sorry that I forgot to write it in the first place.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No. If `v[a.first] == v[b.first]` and `a.second >= b.second` your variant returns true, unlike the original.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function `comp` returns true, when `a` should be found before `b` in the sorted array.

In this implementation, this is the case when either `v[a.first]` is greater than `v[b.first]`. When the `first` members are equal and `a.second` is smaller than `b.second`, it also returns true.

In other words, the sorted array will be sorted to deliver values of `v` in descending order. For values that are equal, the array is sorted according to the `second` variable in ascending order.

Comment: Great explanation, but why do we have to declare the arguments as const? Can't we do without it? I know that comp should not modify the array at all but cant we do without it?

Comment: @Elliot: While comp is still a valid and correct function without the const, it is better to use the const references in order to indicate that the function does not change their values.

Answer (score 6):

In case of sorting it is used to compare two values based on the result of which we can sort the array.More precisely-

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to `bool`. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
>
> The function shall not modify any of its arguments. This can either be a function pointer or [a function object (functors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

Comment: So, this means, that if the value returned is true, then the first value will be considered to go before the second and vice-versa if the value returned is false?

Comment: @Elliot.:Yes! In this case if you return true then a is before b.